# Mocking standalone function of a module for testing using sinon

Tags: typescript, chai, sinon

New to Typescript, need help with mocking with sinon

> childModule.TS

```
export default function go(a:number){ return a * 2 }
```

> ParentModule.ts

```
export {default as go } from './childModule'
```

> testcandidate.ts

```
import  * as ParentModule from './ParentModule'
export function TestGo(num:number){
 let num  = ParentModule.go(num)
}
```

I mocked like this - in spec file but it started making actual call

> testcandidate.spec.ts

```
import {expect} from 'chai'
import  * as ParentModule from './ParentModule'
import sinon from 'sinon'

.....
 let stub = sinon.stub(ParentModule,'go').retunrs(3)
```

but when I make TestGo() call it make actual call not the stub.

How can I mock go() to test that ParentModule.go() is being called once using sinon?